# How to multiply value's occurence time by the key to get the new value?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, count, callable

The goal:

I want to coune the letters in a sentence, and pprint it as a dictionary, where the value is the occurence of the letters in the sentence, not just its time.

[image]

```
import pprint
from collections import Counter

get_the_sentence = input()

# Now scatter the sentence into different letters.

# First remove the period.

get_the_sentence = get_the_sentence.replace(".","")

# Second make all the letters its lower case.

get_the_sentence.lower()

# Third scatter the sentence.

get_the_sentence = list(get_the_sentence)

# Now Counter it, then make the Counter a dict.

Counter_the_letter = Counter(get_the_sentence)

Counter_the_letter = dict(Counter_the_letter)

# Then make the final result.

for letter , time in Counter_the_letter:
time = letter*time

pprint(Counter_the_letter)
```

However I get the Error:

```
python -u "d:\\新建文件夹 (3)\\python_module\\poor_man_bar_chart.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\\新建文件夹 (3)\\python_module\\poor_man_bar_chart.py", line 28, in \<module\>
for letter , time in Counter_the_letter:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
PS C:\\Users\\Babe\>
```

And if I change the

```
for letter , time in Counter_the_letter
```

to

```
for letter , time in Counter_the_letter():
```

Which is Add one more brackets。

then the Error would become:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\\新建文件夹 (3)\\python_module\\poor_man_bar_chart.py", line 28, in \<module\>
for letter , time in Counter_the_letter():
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
PS C:\\Users\\Babe\>
```

by the way I didn't name other variables as dict before.

I wonder what the Error means, an how I can fix it.

My python version is Python 3.10.5.

Comment: Do you see this [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)?

Comment: i.e. `Counter_the_letter.items()`

Answer (score 0):

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

If you want to iterate over key-value pairs of a dictionay, you should use

```py
for key, value in some_dict.items():
   print(key, value)
```

In your case, you are trying to iterate over only keys, which cannot be unpacked to two variables (`letter` and `time`).

---

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

This means you are trying to call a `dict` object, which is not [callable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=glossary#term-callable).

---

You can further simplify your code.

1. Omit the type conversion from `str` to `list`.
2. Omit the type conversion from `Counter` to `dict`.

How to do this without using extra modules:

```py
input_string = "absdav"
unique_chars = set(input_string)  # keys of the expected dict
expected_dict = { ch: input_string.count(ch) for ch in unique_chars }
```

Here, [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) is used to count each unique char in the input string and [`dict comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dict) is used to construct a dictionary.